# Mobile menu breakpoint in Foundation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, zurb-foundation

When I resize the browser, the **mobile menu** shows up at **568x320** where the default breakpoint is.

[image]

So what I want to do is to create a breakpoint something around **900px** to get rid of the menu issue (menu is to big) as you see in the image below but I have no idea how to do it. I've been trying for 5 hrs. straight and I can't figure out. Any help? **[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/99sz3wt0/3/)**. Thanks.

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>

        </li>
        <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right">
            <li class="has-dropdown"> <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>

                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: A link to the example site would be very helpful.

Comment: There is a fiddle link right at the begging.

Comment: Yes, and I checked it. The fiddle links to what you want it to look like, not the actual code you're using. Seeing the actual code in your example screenshots is incredibly helpful for people answering your question.

Comment: @Pixelsmith Your are right, I changed it. I got it to work anyways. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions I found were `.scss` and I'm using plain `.css`. So this is it:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 64.063em) {
    meta.foundation-mq-topbar {
        font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:64.063em)/";
        width: 64.063em;
    }

    .top-bar {
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 2.8125rem;
      line-height: 2.8125rem;
      position: relative;
      background: #333;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .top-bar-section {
      left: 0;
      position: relative;
      width: auto;
      transition: left 300ms ease-out;
    }

    .top-bar-section ul {
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      display: block;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon {
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -16px;
      display:block;
    }
    .top-bar .title-area {
      float: none;
    }
}
```

that solve my issue. I just wanted to change the brakepoint. I wanted the **hamburger** (as many call) to show in `max-width: 64.063em`. So, small and middle devices will show the **hamburger** and the rest will show the regular navigation.

This is the fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/labanino/99sz3wt0/5/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want to replace your menu on all screens with a right hand drop down or if you just want to get rid of it for certain screen widths. I assume it's the second, which is what this example is for.

Depending on what your breakpoints are set at, you can create a second nav menu for the medium screens and then use [visibility classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html) to show the drop down menu for menus from 900px to 1024px.

If you need to adjust or create new breakpoints [here's some helpful info](https://zurb.com/university/lessons/change-foundation-s-default-breakpoints).

It might look something like this: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pixelsmith/guqpnz82/)

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
             <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>

        </li>
        <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right show-for-medium-only">
            <li class="has-dropdown"> <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>

                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right show-for-large-only">
            <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
</section>
</nav>
```